# PHP manual sorting of array mainting its index value i.e key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
$names=array(
  'john'  =>3,
  'dope'  =>2,
  'seiman'=>4,
  'hummar'=>1,
  'vatan' =>5
);
```

I need to sort this array using `foreach` and `for` loop.

Algo 1: Here is my code:

```
foreach($names as $key1=>$val1)
{
    // what to write here?
}
```

---

Using for loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($names)-1;$i++)
{

    for($j=0;$j<count($names)-$i-1;$j++)
    {
        if (($names[$keyarray[$j]])>($names[$keyarray[$j+1]]))
        {
            $temp1=$names[$keyarray[$j]];
            $names[$keyarray[$j]]=   $names[$keyarray[$j+1]];
            $names[$keyarray[$j+1]]=   $temp1;
           // it copies values but not keys
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which sorting algorithm are you going to use and therefore implement?

Answer (score 1):

if you want sort your array by key

```
ksort($names);

Array ( [dope] => 2 [hummar] => 1 [john] => 3 [seiman] => 4 [vatan] => 5 )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

If you want sort your array by value:

```
asort($names);

Array ( [hummar] => 1 [dope] => 2 [john] => 3 [seiman] => 4 [vatan] => 5 )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: without using user defined function?

Comment: if you just sort the array you don't need own functions. use the php functions for this.